# Concatenating `s///` in raku

Tags: raku

I find that a huge
selling point for scripting addicts to join raku would be
having such constructs possible

```
my $w = "Hello world";

$w
  ~~ s/Hello/Hola/
  ~~ s/world/mundo/
  ;

say $w; # » Hola world
```

However I don't seem to be able to write something like this.
As far as I know doing this with the `.subst` method
of `Str` would be too ugly, and this chaining of
`s///` or even also `tr///` basically would be
a gateway drug for `sed` users etc.

My question is if I'm missing something, if something remotely similar to this
is possible somehow in raku. I'm not a beginner and I could
not figure it out.

Comment: `$w .= subst(/Hello/, 'Hola') .= subst(/world/, 'mundo');` is the closest I could get to.  But I guess you could call that too ugly.  Perhaps something with [replace-with](https://docs.raku.org/routine/replace-with) ?

Comment: Ok, I guess it's what I thought. I wanted to write a blog post where I show awk, sed, tr and python users that they can get all this in a `similar` syntax all together in raku, and the part for `awk` it is really very close to raku, so it breaks my heart that I can't do the same for `sed` ;)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could use
[`with`](https://docs.raku.org/language/control#index-entry-control_flow_with)
or `given`

```
with $w {
    s/Hello/Hola/;
    s/world/mundo/;
}
```

[`andthen`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/andthen)

```
$w andthen  s/Hello/Hola/ && s/world/mundo/;
```

or this *ugly* construction

```
$_ := $w;
s/Hello/Hola/;
s/world/mundo/;
```

Comment: Using the with, you could also do a post fix to avoid the brackets: `s/Hello/Hola/ && s/world/mundo/ with $w`.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but trying the `with` and `given` clauses did not work before for me, but now it does, I guess I made some silly mistake somewhere. This is awesome, this is exactly what I wanted

Comment: specially, then the following works
`echo hello world | raku -ne 's/hello/hola/; s/world/mundo/; .say' `
which is just a selling point that gets understressed in the raku community, imho

Comment: `~$ echo "Hello world" | raku -pe 's/Hello/Hola/; s/world/mundo/;'` #Hola mundo

Comment: @margolari jubilatious1's suggestion is great if you can hoist the value to the main topic.  But if not, you can shave off a few more characters by using the reduction operator: `[&&] s///,s///,s///,… with $foo`.

Comment: This is very cool, I did not know this, I'll put this in my blog and post it on reddit. I did not know exactly what is the Type of a `s///` expression, that is why I didn't quite not how to `mconcat` or to reduce it

Answer (score 8):

Some excellent answers so far (including comments).

Utilizing Raku's non-destructive  `S///` operator is often useful when doing multiple (successive) substitutions. In the Raku REPL:

```raku
> my $w = "Hello world";
Hello world
> given $w {S/Hello/Hola/ andthen S/world/mundo/};
Hola mundo
> say $w;
Hello world
```

Once you're happy with your code, you can assign the result to a new variable:

```raku
> my $a = do given $w {S/Hello/Hola/ andthen S/world/mundo/};
Hola mundo
> say $a
Hola mundo
```

Taking this idea a little further, I wrote the following 'baby Raku' translation script and saved it as `Bello_Gallico.p6`. It's fun to run!

```raku
my $caesar = "Gallia est omnis divisa in partes tres";
my $trans1 = do given $caesar {
 S/Gallia/Gaul/ andthen
 S/est/is/ andthen
 S/omnis/a_whole/ andthen
 S/divisa/divided/ andthen
 S/in/into/ andthen
 S/partes/parts/ andthen
 S/tres/three/ 
};
put $caesar;
put $trans1;
```

HTH.

https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#S///_non-destructive_substitution

Comment: this is also very useful, and looks nice `sedish` too!

Comment: @margolari Thank you! For some reason syntax-highlighting isn't working in my browser...hopefully it is in yours...or someone can edit to correct.

Comment: @margolari just like I showed with the wamba's, with this one, because `andthen` is a infix operator and not a control word, you can also do `my $trans1 = [andthen] S///, S///, S/// … with $caesar` to be non-destructive :-)

Comment: @user0721090601 Very clever! Your code worked perfectly. However I tried using `reduce &infix:<andthen>,` to substitute for `[andthen]` as per the reduction metaoperator Docs page, and it didn't work. Any thoughts? See: https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#index-entry-[]_(reduction_metaoperators)